# Convert column to row in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have the following Python pandas dataframe:

```
     fruits | numFruits
---------------------
0  | apples |   10
1  | grapes |   20
2  |  figs  |   15
```

I want:

```
                 apples | grapes | figs
-----------------------------------------
Market 1 Order |    10  |   20   |  15
```

I have looked at pivot(), pivot_table(), Transpose and unstack() and none of them seem to give me this. Pandas newbie, so all help appreciated.

Comment: If you are interested about difference of performace, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862406/performance-of-creating-new-dataframe)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print (df.set_index('fruits').T)
fruits     apples  grapes  figs
numFruits      10      20    15
```

If need rename columns, it is a bit complicated:

```
print (df.rename(columns={'numFruits':'Market 1 Order'})
         .set_index('fruits')
         .rename_axis(None).T)
                apples  grapes  figs
Market 1 Order      10      20    15
```

Another faster solution is use [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.numFruits.values.reshape(1,-1), 
                    index=['Market 1 Order'], 
                    columns=df.fruits.values))

                apples  grapes  figs
Market 1 Order      10      20    15
```

**Timings**:

```
#[30000 rows x 2 columns] 
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)    
print (df)


In [55]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([df.numFruits.values], ['Market 1 Order'], df.fruits.values))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.4 s per loop

In [56]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.numFruits.values.reshape(1,-1), index=['Market 1 Order'], columns=df.fruits.values))
The slowest run took 5.64 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 424 µs per loop

In [57]: %timeit (df.rename(columns={'numFruits':'Market 1 Order'}).set_index('fruits').rename_axis(None).T)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.94 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hi ...In this question there are only 3 columns what If we have 10 columns and we need to retain 8 of them and just use the other 2 to reshape the data ?

Comment: It seems you need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), but without data hard answer. Maybe the best is create new question with sample data, desired output and what do you try (your code)

Comment: I just created a new question please review.

Answer (score 10):

```
pd.DataFrame([df.numFruits.values], ['Market 1 Order'], df.fruits.values)

                apples  grapes  figs
Market 1 Order      10      20    15
```

---

*Refer to jezrael's enhancement of this concept.  `df.numFruits.values.reshape(1, -1)` is more efficient.*

Comment: @jezrael that was me being sloppy.   Overhead for pandas figuring out that I had a list of arrays.  So much simpler to give it the 2-D array in the first place as you did.

Comment: @jezrael The concept is the same.  I'll edit my answer to point to your update of it.

Comment: @jezrael also, I think that overhead is small for larger arrays... maybe

Comment: I was a bit confused, but I think now it is super. thank you.

Comment: @jezrael nope!  I'm wrong... for larger arrays, it's even worse.

Comment: I create new question about explanation, I hope you get nice answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use transpose api of pandas as follow:

```
df.transpose()
```

Considering df as your pandas dataframe