# how could perform column to row transform on DataFrame like this

Tags: python, dataframe

I want transform column data to rows like this,how could I perform this?programming language is python

original data:

```
    data    month   user_id
0   3782.0  01      1
1   1882.0  02      1
2   536.0   03      2
3   526.0   04      2
```

transformed data:

```
user_id mo_1 mo_2 mo_3 mo_4
1       3782 1882 
2                 536  526
```

original data definition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1},
                   'month': {0: '01', 1: '02', 2: '03', 3: '04'},
                  'data': {0: 3782., 1: 1882., 2: 536., 3: 526.},})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change row values to column headers, you need to use `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['user_id', 'month'], inplace=True)
df = df.unstack()

           data                      
month        01      02     03     04
user_id                              
1        3782.0  1882.0  536.0  526.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861846/convert-row-to-column-in-python-pandas) you need to use transpose by T.

```
print (df.set_index('fruits').T)
fruits     apples  grapes  figs
numFruits      10      20    15
```

Comment: thanks,but your answer ignore the column name :).and the user_id is  not unique.