# Transform non numeric rows into columns with custom column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([['7690d79f','Pos'],['7690d79f','Neg'],['7690d79f','Pos'],['7690d79f','Neu'],\
                       ['6690d79f','Pos'],['6690d79f','Neg'],['6690d79f','Pos'],['6690d79f','Neu']]\
                       ,columns=['id', 'vote'])
```

which is:

```
    id         vote
0   7690d79f    Pos
1   7690d79f    Neg
2   7690d79f    Pos
3   7690d79f    Neu
4   6690d79f    Pos
5   6690d79f    Neg
6   6690d79f    Pos
7   6690d79f    Neu
```

I want to pivot rows to columns such that, I get a resultDF as

```
id  vote_1 vote_2 vote_3 vote_4
7690d79f Pos  Neg Pos Neu
6690d79f Pos  Neg Pos Neu
```

If it helps, there is no more than 4 votes per ids.

Though this is similar to

1. [Python Pandas: Convert Rows as Column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers)
2. [Convert row to column in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861846/convert-row-to-column-in-python-pandas)

But unfortunately, none of them works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df1 = df.groupby('id')['vote'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist())).unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel().values + 1
df1.add_prefix('vote_').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         id vote_1 vote_2 vote_3 vote_4
0  6690d79f    Pos    Neg    Pos    Neu
1  7690d79f    Pos    Neg    Pos    Neu
```

Comment: Perfect, this works, now going to google about `unstack` and `droplevel()`