# Pandas: dataframe transformation using pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transformation

I have a data frame in the below format:

```
Date        Id       A         B         C          D        E
2018-01-28 5937.0 11.000000 11.000000 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000

2018-01-21 5937.0 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000
```

I want to change the data into the below format:

```
             Id       2018-01-28         2018-01-21
A           5937.0   11.000000          10.000000
B           5937.0   11.000000          10.000000
C           5937.0   10.000000          10.000000
D           5937.0   10.000000          10.000000
E           5937.0   10.000000          10.000000
```

What is the best method to carry out following transformation. I have been using pivot but its not working(I am not very good with pivot)

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861846/convert-row-to-column-in-python-pandas. It can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) followed by [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Date','Id']).stack().unstack(0).reset_index(0)

print(df1)
Date      Id  2018-01-21  2018-01-28
A     5937.0        10.0        11.0
B     5937.0        10.0        11.0
C     5937.0        10.0        10.0
D     5937.0        10.0        10.0
E     5937.0        10.0        10.0
```

---

```
df1=df.set_index(['Date','Id']).stack().unstack(0).reset_index(0).rename_axis(None,1)

print(df1)
       Id  2018-01-21  2018-01-28
A  5937.0        10.0        11.0
B  5937.0        10.0        11.0
C  5937.0        10.0        10.0
D  5937.0        10.0        10.0
E  5937.0        10.0        10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `melt` and `pivot_table`:

```
(df.melt(['Date', 'Id'])
   .pivot_table(index=['variable', 'Id'], columns='Date', values='value')
   .reset_index())


Date variable      Id  2018-01-21  2018-01-28
0           A  5937.0        10.0        11.0
1           B  5937.0        10.0        11.0
2           C  5937.0        10.0        10.0
3           D  5937.0        10.0        10.0
4           E  5937.0        10.0        10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pivot:

```
(df.pivot_table(values=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], columns=["Id", "Date"])
    .unstack()
    .reset_index(1) # Multi-index level 1 = Id
    .rename_axis(None, 1)) # Set columns name to None (not Date)
```

Output:

```
Date      Id  2018-01-21  2018-01-28
A     5937.0        10.0        11.0
B     5937.0        10.0        11.0
C     5937.0        10.0        10.0
D     5937.0        10.0        10.0
E     5937.0        10.0        10.0
```